# ng2-ckeditor 404 (Not Found) angular2

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I added ng2/CKEDitor with cmd npm install ng2-ckeditor
it well installed 
there is an example https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor 
I did the same things 
and I added also this script in my index

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.8/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

where I call view where I put `<ckedito></ckeditor>` 
I get this error

```
 zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:9000/ng2-ckeditor 404 (Not Found)

    Error loading http://localhost:9000/ng2-ckeditor as "ng2-ckeditor" from http://localhost:9000/dist/app.component.js
```

but I worry because they mentioned in example: Sample(ES6)
and in my tsconfig i have es5

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main"
  ]
}
```

when I add this I get error `directives: [ CKEditor]`
thanks

Comment: Do you have a `system.config.js`? If so, please post it.

Comment: yeesss I have my system.config.js

Comment: You have to import `ckeditor` from node_modules and have to map it as well in `systemjs.config.js`.

Comment: I added this to system.config.js     'ng2-ckeditor':               'node_modules/ng2-ckeditor',

i have always the same error

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to the `map` block in the SystemJS configuration:

```
'ng2-ckeditor': 'node_modules/ng2-ckeditor/lib/ng2-ckeditor.js'
```

Comment: always I get error

ng2-ckeditor works with angular2 version beta

and my project angular2 rc1
this is cant cause a problem ?

Comment: Obviously yes! Because of the package renaming. For example `angular2/core` becomes `@angular/core` in RC...

Comment: should I edit code of import in ng2-ckeditor ??
as the example you wrote !

Comment: I cant get to work with ng2-ckeditor with angular2-rc1 ?
because ng2-ckeditor is developed with angular2 I cant update it 

especially in file ckeditor.es6 when I change angular2 to @angular
I get this Module is not installed