# Angular 2 configuration "ng2-ckeditor.js"

Tags: javascript, angular

I am facing the following error while open my project.

[image]

The strange thing is that I had it up but this error appears now, although I haven't modify any config files.

The solution that I found in the following link, does not work for me:
[ng2-ckeditor 404 (Not Found) angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703351/ng2-ckeditor-404-not-found-angular2)

That means that I placed 
'ng2-ckeditor': 'node_modules/ng2-ckeditor/lib/ng2-ckeditor.js'
in the map block in the SystemJS configuration but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you check it? https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor

Comment: I did. The solution was "dummy". Just cleared browsers cache.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check the instalation items from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor 
I think you will need to activate command for install ckeditor module to your system by:

- JSPM : jspm install npm:ng2-ckeditor
- NPM : npm install ng2-ckeditor